# How simplify Gulp task for hard folders structure?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I working with gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps, browsersync and i have project with hard folder structure for sass stylesheets.
Now task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  // bootstrap compilation
    gulp.src('./sass/bootstrap.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/'))

  // global theme stylesheet compilation
    gulp.src('./sass/global/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass/global'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/global/css'))

  gulp.src('./sass/apps/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass/apps'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/apps/css'))

  gulp.src('./sass/pages/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass/pages'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/pages/css'))

  // theme layouts compilation
  gulp.src('./sass/layouts/layout4/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass/layouts/layout4'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/layouts/layout4/css'))

  gulp.src('./sass/layouts/layout4/themes/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: true, sourceRoot: '/sass/layouts/layout4/themes'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/layouts/layout4/css/themes'))
});
```

But i think this task may be simpler.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to shorten the code and improve its maintainability by defining every `*.scss` processing step just once.

Your source directories with the `*.scss` files follow the same pattern, except for the first and last ones:

```
source files:     './sass/{path}/*.scss'
source maps root: '/sass/{path}'
destination root: './assets/{path}/css'
```

Where the `{path}` is the source path core - "global", "layouts/layout4" etc.  How about storing the the path cores in an array and process the array by a local function?

For example, let us use an array of objects, where the `src` key is the source path core and the optional `dest` key can override the default destination root pattern:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  // src: './sass/{src}/*.scss', sourceRoot: '/sass/{src}'
  // dest: './assets/{dest}', default './assets/{src}/css'
  var stylesheets = [
        {src: '', dest: '/global/plugins/bootstrap/css'},
        {src: '/global'},
        {src: '/apps'},
        {src: '/pages'},
        {src: '/layouts/layout4'},
        {src: '/layouts/layout4/themes', dest: '/layouts/layout4/css/themes'}
      ],
      streams = stylesheets.map(function (stylesheet) {
        var src = stylesheet.src,
            dest = stylesheet.dest || src + '/css';
        return gulp.src('./sass' + src + '/*.scss')
          .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
          .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
          .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
            includeContent: true,
            sourceRoot: '/sass' + src
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets' + dest + '/'));
      });
  return merge.apply(this, streams);
});
```

Other improvements: If you do not want an error in an `*.scss` file to crash the gulp task chain, you should listen to the "error" event of the `gulp-sass` plugin.  If you want to make the gulp task chainable, you should return the result of the last `pipe()` call from it.

Integrating tasks like `gulp-livereload`, `gulp-minify-css` or `gulp-autoprefixer` would be just a matter of adding the appropriate `pipe()` call to the chain and all files will be affected.

**UPDATE**: Fix returning one stream processing all files from the task by using the [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) module.  The sequence of `.pipe()` calls cannot continue by another `.src()` starting chain.  Single stylesheets will not be produced in a sequence, but the caller will be able to wait for all of them being produced.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for Ferdinand but I get this error when running gulp. "gulp.src is not a function" - what am I missing?

gulp 3.9.0, gulp-sass 2.2.0, gulp-sourcemaps 1.6.0

Comment: You're right, @wind_kind.  I made a mistake in the original post when concatenating all streams coming from the sub-tasks.  I edited the post to fix it.  Thanks!